# Unable to Retrive Ajax Response in some Records

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I am using onclick jquery event to append ajax response in modal box.My purpose is to display a form with auto Filled Data in modal box that comes from ajax Response according to id from mysql database.But it is not dispaying form for some  users.
my code for above explained is here

Jquery code:

```
$(document).on("click",".edit_recent_member_form",function(e){

            e.preventDefault();
            $("#overlay").addClass("load_show");
            $("#formModal .modal-body").html("");
            var edit_recent_member_form="edit_recent_member_form";
            var mem_id=$(this).attr("mem_id");

            var datastring="edit_members_form="+edit_recent_member_form+"&mem_id="+mem_id;
            //alert(datastring);
            $.ajax({
        url:"modules/my_members/edit_member_form.php",
        type:"post",
        dataType:"json",
        data:datastring,
        }).done(function(data){

         var html=data["html"];
        //alert(html);
        $("#formModal .modal-body").append(html);
            $('#formModal').modal({
                show:true
                //backdrop:'static'
            });
            /////
            $(".mi-multiup").dropzone({ url: "modules/my_members/ajax.php?var=edit_profile_pic" ,acceptedFiles : ".jpeg,.jpg,.png,.gif,.JPEG,.JPG,.PNG,.GIF" });
var sendingHandler = function(file, xhr, formData) {
    formData.append('mem_id',mem_id);
    //formData.append('img_name', $(".img_name").val());
    //formData.append('img_desc', $(".img_desc").val());
};
$('.mi-multiup').each(function() {
    Dropzone.forElement(this).on('sending', sendingHandler);
});


            //////

      $("#overlay").removeClass("load_show");
        });

});
```

Ajax code:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['edit_members_form']))
{
$mem_id=$_REQUEST['mem_id'];
$html='<div class="panel panel-default">

                                    <form class="form-horizontal form-border">
                                    <div class="alert alert-success successbox">
                             Selected Record is Saved Successfully.
                                </div>
                                        <div class="alert alert-danger dangerbox"></div>
                                        <div class="panel-heading">
                                            Edit Member
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="panel-body">
                                        <div class="form-group">
                                                <label class="control-label col-md-2">Login</label>                                             
                                                <div class="col-md-10">
                                        <input type="text" class="form-control user_login" placeholder="" value="'.get_edit_member_detail($mem_id,"user_login",$page).'">
                                                </div><!-- /.col -->
                                            </div><!-- /form-group -->
<div class="form-group">
                                <label class="col-lg-2 control-label">Category</label>
                                <div class="col-lg-10">
                                    <select class="form-control chzn-select category">
                                    <option>None selected or enter new category</option>
                                    '.get_category_detail($mem_id,$page,"none").'
                                    </select>
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="newcategory" value="" placeholder="Enter a new category" size="28" />
                                </div><!-- /.col -->
                            </div><!-- /form-group -->

                            <div><a href="#" class="btn btn-success btn-sm show_dropzone">Upload Image</a></div>
                                            <div class="form-horizontal form-border" style="display:none;">
                                            <h3>Click on area to upload new image</h3>

                                            <div class="dropzone mi-multiup"></div>
                                            </div>



                                        </div>
                                        <div class="panel-footer">
                                            <div class="text-right">
                                                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-success update_member_info" mem_id='.$mem_id.'>Update Member Information</button>

                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </form>
                                </div><!-- /panel -->';



$list = array('html' =>$html);
    echo json_encode($list);
    }
```

and it is the code whose onclick all work should be done

```
<td>
                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-sm edit_recent_member_form tip" title="Edit User" data-toggle="modal" mem_id="'.$id.'"><i class="fa fa-user-md fa-lg"></i></a></td>
```

please any solution.

Answer (score 0):

May be this solution. Add this code in ajax calling

```
url:"modules/my_members/edit_member_form.php",
type:"post",
dataType:"json",
data:datastring,
async: false
```